# MySQL performance when updating row with FK

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
spies     | 
--------- | 
id        | PK
weapon_id | FK
name      |   


weapons
--------- |
id        | PK
name      |
```

I'm trying to clarify whether there is a difference in these two SQL updates (when using MySQL innoDB)

Query 1:

`UPDATE spies SET name = 'Bond', weapon_id = 1 WHERE id = 1`

OR

Query 2:

`UPDATE spies SET name = 'Bond' WHERE id = 1`

I have heard that when the updating a row with a FK creates read-only lock (not sure if that's the correct term) on the parent.

Would using Query 2 avoid the lock on the parent table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following schema:
*(Rem stmts left in for your convenience)* :

```
-- drop table if exists spies;
create table spies
(   id int primary key,
    weapon_id int not null,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    key(weapon_id),
    foreign key (weapon_id) references weapons(id)
)engine=InnoDB;

-- drop table if exists weapons;
create table weapons
(   id int primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null
)engine=InnoDB;

insert weapons(id,name) values (1,'slingshot'),(2,'Ruger');
insert spies(id,weapon_id,name) values (1,2,'Sally');
-- truncate table spies;
```

Now, we have 2 processes, P1 and P2. Best to test where P1 is perhaps MySQL Workbench and P2 is a MySql Command-line window. In other words, you have to set this up as separate connections and right. You would have to have a meticulous eye for step-by-step running these in the proper fashion (described in the **Narrative** below) and see its impact on the other process window.

Consider the following queries, keeping in mind that a mysql query not wrapped in an explicit transaction is itself an implicit transaction. But below, I swung for explicit:

Q1:

```
START TRANSACTION;
-- place1
UPDATE spies SET name = 'Bond', weapon_id = 1 WHERE id = 1;
-- place2
COMMIT;
```

Q2:

```
START TRANSACTION;
-- place1
UPDATE spies SET name = 'Bond' WHERE id = 1;
-- place2
COMMIT;
```

Q3:

```
START TRANSACTION;
-- place1
SELECT id into @mine_to_use from weapons where id=1 FOR UPDATE; -- place2
-- place3
COMMIT;
```

Q4:

```
START TRANSACTION;
-- place1
SELECT id into @mine_to_use from spies where id=1 FOR UPDATE; -- place2
-- place3
COMMIT;
```

Q5 (hodge podge of queries):

```
SELECT * from weapons;
SELECT * from spies;
```

### Narrative

***Q1:*** When P1 starts to begin **Q1**, and gets to place2, it has obtained an exclusive row-level update lock in both tables weapons and spies for the id=1 row (2 rows total, 1 row in each table). This can be proved by P2 starting to run Q3, getting to place1, but blocking on place2, and only being freed when P1 gets around to calling COMMIT. Everything I just said about P2 running Q3 is ditto for P2 running Q4. In summary, on the P2 screen, place2 freezes until the P1 Commit.

A note again about implicit transactions. *Your real* Q1 query is going to perform this very fast and coming out of it will do an implicit commit. However, the prior paragraph breaks it down were you to have more time-costly routines running.

***Q2:*** When P1 starts to begin **Q2**, and gets to place2, it has obtained an exclusive row-level update lock in both tables weapons and spies for the id=1 row (2 rows total, 1 row in each table). However, P2 has no issues with Q3 blocking `weapons`, but P2 has block issues running Q4 at place2 `spies`.

So, the differences between Q1 and Q2 come down to MySQL knowing that the FK index is not relevant to a column in the UPDATE, and the manual states that in **Note1** below.

When P1 runs Q1, P2 has no problems the read-only non-lock aquiring Q5 types of queries. The only issues are what data renditions P2 sees based on the ISOLATION LEVEL in place.

**Note1**: From the MySQL Manual Page entitled [Locks Set by Different SQL Statements in InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html):

> If a FOREIGN KEY constraint is defined on a table, any insert, update,
>   or delete that requires the constraint condition to be checked sets
>   shared record-level locks on the records that it looks at to check the
>   constraint. InnoDB also sets these locks in the case where the
>   constraint fails.

The above is why the behavior of ***Q2:*** is such that P2 is free to perform an UPDATE or acquire an UPDATE exclusive momentary lock on `weapons`. This is because the engine is not performing an UPDATE with P1 on weapon_id and thus does not have a row-level lock in that table.

To pull this back to 50,000 feet, one's biggest concern is the duration at which a lock is held either in an implicit transaction (one with no START/COMMIT), or explicit transaction before a COMMIT. A peer process can be prohibited from acquiring its need for an UPDATE in theory indefinitely. But each attempt at acquiring that lock is governed by its setting for [innodb_lock_wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout). What that means is, by default, after about 60 seconds it times out. For a view of your setting, run:

```
select @@innodb_lock_wait_timeout;
```

For me, at the moment, it is 50 (seconds).

Comment: So in summary what you're saying is that in order to avoid having an exclusive update lock on the weapons table, doing the update on the spies table without specifying the weapon_id should avoid this?

Comment: Do you want to join me in the [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) chat room as this may go on for a while, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Why not run **EXPLAIN** for this query and check it for yourself?

So, lets run!!

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE spies SET name = 'Bond', weapon_id = 1 WHERE id = 1\G
```

And check for number of rows that this query is scanning for, check for **ROWS** section and see how many rows its scanning.

Do the same for the below one as well.

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE spies SET name = 'Bond' WHERE id = 1\G
```

Now, coming to your question, INNODB will lock every update you are making on the each row in a table. But remember, this is a row level locking.

> So, to answer your question, updating a row with or without a foreign key will not make a difference if its the same row and the same table.
>
> It will make a difference if its a different row or different table.

Comment: This answer seems to contradict the first answer. So I'm not sure which one is correct. What you're saying is that it doesn't matter whether weapon_id is specified in the UPDATE statement, the weapons table will always have an explicit update lock due to the FK constraint on the spies table. Is that right?