# How to simulate innodb_lock_wait_timeout error?

Tags: mysql

I'm getting innodb_lock_wait_timeout error. I want to simulate this error to understand exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: I can help you with this, maybe in a chat room, you come back and do a self answer (if no one answers here after a while) [chat link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290)

Comment: Or follow along this I wrote up here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38626364

Comment: Ok thanks @Drew I'll have look

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/6000336

Comment: @Drew I just have forgotten to commit my transaction that is why I got that error. Anyway thanks for help. I also learned something new.